# Postgres 7 strange error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I run an update script on my SQL 7.4.27 DB. I add some constraints and change some column values.
The script is to long for posting here.

The query gives me the following error:

```
    ERROR:  could not find trigger 96099812
********** Error **********

ERROR: could not find trigger 96099812
SQL state: XX000
```

Where can I begin to look for the solution? The error message doesn't give me anything that could help.

Comment: Are you sure about version 7.4? It's EOL for years. First thing to do: make a backup!

Comment: Backup is done... and the version is right for sure. I am aware of the outdated issue but my hands are tied here

Comment: I'd find somewhere else where they aren't so tied, personally ... eventually, they'll be running old virtual hardware to run an old OS to run the old Pg version. I've been there (business platform from 1983, still running when I left the company in 2012) and I assure you, the longer you wait to deal with an upgrade the deeper the hole you're digging for yourself. Can't afford downtime? You'll never be _more_ able to afford it, and likely _less_ than now in future. It's only going to get harder.

Comment: Start looking in `pg_trigger` - that number is probably the OID of trigger entry. That table should have the OID of the function it calls - follow it to `pg_proc`. Either someone has been manually hacking the system catalogues, you've got disk corruption or hit a bug (which version of 7.4?). Allow yourself several hours to sort this out.

Answer (score 2):

7.4 (and up to 8.2 IIRC, haven't double checked in the release notes) had some plan invalidation issues in PL/PgSQL. It'd prepare a plan, then run the cached plan even if DDL had run that'd since caused the plan to make no sense.

That'd be my first suspect for this kind of issue, but it's hard to be too sure - I didn't really get started with PostgreSQL until well after 7.4 came out *in late 2003*. Yes, that's ten years ago.

I'd take a look in `pg_trigger` to see if the entry is there, but I couldn't tell you much about what its presence of absence *means* without seeing the code you ran.